# HTML / CSS Column Scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, multiple-columns

I have two columns on my page.

The left column is one long list, the right is smaller.

When I scroll up and down I want the right column to float with the page not be static.

I've managed to get this working using this css:

```
    .connected {
        min-height:100px;
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .connected.right {
        position: fixed; 
        min-height:100px;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
    }
```

and can be seen here on this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8fxosb5f/1/).

The issue I have is if the right column is long, then it doesn't move at all and the bottom entries aren't accessible.

Is there any way to get the right column to scroll but only until you reach the end of it, then it is fixed untill you start scrolling back up ?

Thanks

Comment: There are 3 options. 1) Use Javascript for it. 2) Set a overflow so a Scrollbar will appear. 3) Make it smaller, like smaller font-size or less items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting `overflow: auto;` to the right column?

```
.connected.right {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height:100px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

This will set a scroll to it and will allow scrolling until the very end of the column.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8fxosb5f/2/

Or you can remove the window scroll by setting `overflow: auto` to both columns. But that way you need to set a certain height of those columns. The result might not be what you need, still here's a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/8fxosb5f/3/

Here's a really rough code, but I think you will manage to set it to fit your needs: (it requires jQuery)

```
var columnHeight = $('.right').outerHeight(true);

var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= columnHeight) {
        $('.right').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: -(columnHeight - windowHeight)
        });
    } else {
        $('.right').css({
            position: 'static',
            top: 'auto'
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8fxosb5f/5/

Comment: Thanks the first example is nearly what I'm trying to do..
I was hoping to have both columns scroll down and the the right fix when it got to the bottom..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you actually want. Can you post a picture or something? I'm guessing you are going to need `javascript` to do this, but still a simple "drawing" would be nice

Comment: Not sure how I can draw this.
Currently both columns are longer than the page.
As you scroll down the page, you also scroll down the columns. When you get to the bottom of the right column I'd like it to stop and the left to continue scrolling down.

Comment: But you want when the right columns content ends, the column to continue scrolling (something like position: fixed) as it's scrolled to the end?

Comment: Thanks that seems to work well.. any idea how I can stop the slight layout change when it becomes FIXED ?

Comment: Yep, just set the `float` to `left` on the right column: https://jsfiddle.net/8fxosb5f/6/

Comment: any idea how to make the right column stay at the top if the column is smaller than the visible window ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80065/discussion-between-ivanka-todorova-and-tom).

Comment: Still having issues with this.. if right column is longer than left... then I lose the end of that column

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the css is incorrect

```
.connected.right {
        position: fixed; 
        min-height:100px;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
    }
```

change it to

```
.connected .right {
        position: fixed; 
        min-height:100px;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
    }
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8fxosb5f/4/)

Comment: It's working like intended, but he want to make the right div dynamic until you reach the last entry, than be fixed and if you scroll up, it's dynamic again.

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't fix the issue