# HTML / CSS / Jquery Scrolling Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

As a follow up to my **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706632/html-css-column-scrolling)** yesterday regarding HTML / CSSS Column scrolling.

This is working but I have an issue when the right column is shorter than the screen height, as soon as I start scrolling that column moves to the bottom of the page.

This **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3a0575fu/)** shows what I mean.

The jquery being used is:

```
var columnHeight = $('.right').outerHeight(true);

var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= columnHeight) {
        $('.right').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: -(columnHeight - windowHeight)
        });
    } else {
        $('.right').css({
            position: 'static',
            top: 'auto'
        });
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to archive is if the right column is not as long as the screen then it should stay at the top.

If it's longer than the screen then it should scroll, but stop when it reaches the bottom.

The left column needs to be able to continue scrolling if needed.

Hope this makes some sense !
Thanks

****UPDATE****
Setting the right column to FIXED stops it scrolling to the bottom of the list if it is longer than the screen.

Comment: If you set `position: fixed` but don't set a `top` value the `ul` will stay where it was originally placed: https://jsfiddle.net/3a0575fu/1/. Is that what you want?

Comment: Note quite.. https://jsfiddle.net/3a0575fu/14/ shows what happens when both lists are quite log..  you can no long scroll down on the right list

Comment: any one any other ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is solved. Just add position:fixed in your css

```
 .connected.right {
                min-height:100px;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
                position:fixed;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/3a0575fu/13/)**.
I hope this works for you. Just comment if it does not.

```js
var columnHeight = $('.right').outerHeight(true);

var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= columnHeight) {
    $('.right').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: -(columnHeight - windowHeight)
    });
  } else {
    $('.right').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 'auto'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.connected {
  min-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.connected.right {
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" width="65%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <ul class="connected" id="new">
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <ul class="connected right" id="old">
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>AAA</li>

      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Please describe the changes you made to the code of the question, and include the amendments in your answer.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I've updated the JSFiddle only as previous fiddle was working well but when Scrolled to the top it use to change the position but this works well.

Comment: That may be true, however you should include your code in your answer. If jsfiddle goes down (as it frequently does) your answer will be worthless, and probably downvoted.